# How do you interpolate the local maxima of a set of points in more than 3 dimensions?

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation, interpolation

I have a set of about 400 points each with 6 coordinates and one scalar value. How can I find out where the local maxima are?

Comment: As a friend of 9k9 (whose not really written much if he helps to get a helpful answer) I would add that he has one function from six dimensional space (say a, b, c, d, e, f) which outputs a scalar. Unfortunately he only has the value of this function at 400 points in abcdef space and has no way of evaluating it at an arbitrary point (which we think rules out stuff like the simplex algorithm). Thanks!

Comment: One has to understand how those 400 points are situated in the 6D space. On the basis of their positions one can declare some points to be "neighbors", thus creating a graph with points as vertices. Then do exhaustive search for local maxima in the graph: take each vertex, compare the value with its neighbors... Also, be aware of the site [scicomp.se].